# Apple sign in with identity server 4 asp.net callback returns error 302 not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, apple-sign-in

I am implementing apple sign in with my identity server 4 in asp.net 6, the flow works and I get id token from apple with the user information, when it makes a post request to the callback path in my console network panel I see an error 302 not found, and in the payload I see my id_token and when i decode it it has my user information

this is the request to call back

error 302:
[image]

this is my payload with the correct id_token:
[image]

and this is my addAuthentication code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    //options.ApiName = "profile";
    options.Authority = "https://dm-it-smp-dev-cp-appsvc-01.azurewebsites.net";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Audience = "users";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidateAudience = false,
    };
}).AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "608131721549-3o4goli5gob23io1l08cb4fq33eorehk.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    options.ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
}).AddOpenIdConnect("apple", async options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://appleid.apple.com"; // disco doc: https://appleid.apple.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

    options.ClientId = "identity.signin.service"; // Service ID
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    options.ResponseMode = "form_post";
    //options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    //options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    options.DisableTelemetry = true;
    options.CallbackPath = "/testcb";
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("name");
    options.UsePkce = false; // apple does not currently support PKCE (April 2021)
    options.DisableTelemetry = true;
    options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
    {
        AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize",
        TokenEndpoint = "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token"
    };
    options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
    {
        context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientSecret = tokenService.CreateNewToken();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = "https://appleid.apple.com";
    var jwks = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys");
    options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys = new JsonWebKeySet(jwks).Keys;
    options.ProtocolValidator.RequireNonce = false;
}).AddCookie("Cookies");
```

and those are my APIs:

```
 [HttpGet("signin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TestChallenge()
        {
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return Challenge("apple");
        }



        [HttpPost("testcb")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CallbackApple([FromBody] AppleForm appleForm)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

the callbackpath matches the redirect url from my apple portal service id in enable sign in config, what may be the problem?